# How does jetpack compose dynamically register custom component libraries

Tags: forms, dynamic, android-jetpack-compose

I am now using a json scheme to dynamically render the form.

When I need to render a specific form item, such as Input, I don't want to bind a fixed component library, such as `Material Design`, but want to expose a `register` method to allow users to dynamically register their own component library

```kotlin
// for example
class FormEngine {
  val componentMap = HasMap<String, @Composable () -> Unit>()

  // expose a register function
  fun register(name: String, component: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    // do register to the component list...
    componentMap.put(name, component)
  }
}

// usage
FormEngine().register("input", OwnInputComponent)
```

Then I can render the form using the components they pass in.

```kotlin
val InputComponent = FormEngine().componentMap["input"]
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this? Thanks!!!

Comment: what's problem with your code?

Comment: The problem is I can't register the component like the code. 

`FormEngine().register("input", OwnInputComponent)`, 

That's the goal I want to achieve. Cause `OwnInputComponent` is a `@Composable` function

Comment: You can't pass composable by reference, try `register("input", { OwnInputComponent() })` instead

Comment: Actually, I don't want to instance the `@Composable` function when `register`, cause the composable function also has some parameters, I just want to pass a reference

Comment: Actually this line `{ OwnInputComponent() }` is not executing the component, it only creates a lambda function, which will return it when executed.

Comment: Yeah, I know this is really like a callback, thanks for the idea.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally, I get it works by defining an interface and then implementing it, like this below

```kotlin
interface FormComponent {
  @Composable
  fun Component(modifier: Modifier) {}
}

class Input: FormComponent {
  @Composable
  overwrite fun Component(modifier: Modifier) {
    // ... your Input component here
  }
}

class FormEngine {
  private var formItemMap = hashMapOf()
  fun register(name: String, component: FormComponent) {
    formItemMap[name] = component
  }
  
  operator fun get(name: String) = formItemMap[name]
}

// register
FormEngine().register("input", Input())

// usage
FormEngin()["input"].Component(...args)
```

Comment: This will not complile `private var formItemMap = hashMapOf()` has no type information.